# Error al obtener el máximo y mínimo de valores enteros ingresados por el usuario

Tags: python, ordenamiento

Hice lo siguiente:
[image: Codigo]

Pero cuando pongo de menor el número 4 no me lo lee:

[image: Codigo]

El código en si es:

```
A=int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))
B=int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))
C=int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))
D=int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))
if(A==B==C==D):
    print('Los números son iguales '+str(A)+' = '+str(B)+' = '+str(C)+' = '+str(D))
else:
    if(A>B and A>C and A>D):
        print('El número mayor es: '+str(A))
    else:
        if(B>A and B>C and B>D):
            print('El número mayor es: '+str(B))
        else:
            if(C>A and C>B and C>D):
                print('El número mayor es: '+str(C))
            else:
                if(D>A and D>B and D>C):
                    print('El número mayor es: '+str(D))

                    if(A<B and A<C and A<D):
                       print('El número menor es: '+str(A))
                    else:
                       if(B<A and B<C and B<D):
                           print('El número menor es: '+str(B))
                       else:
                          if(C<A and C<B and C<D):
                              print('El número menor es: '+str(C))
                          else:
                              if(D<A and D<B and D<C):
                                  print('El número menor es: '+str(D)).
```

Éste es el algoritmo que realice es algo muy básico pero no me funciona el siguiente paso:

```
if(D<A and D<B and D<C):
    print('El número menor es: 'str(D))
```

sinceramente no se cual es el fallo si me colaboran se los agradezco mucho. ¿Qué me aconsejan?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Arreglemos tu pregunta.. el codigo siempre como texto.. Que estas tratando de hacer? que es lo que no funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese código da miedo para algo tan sencillo como es obtener el número mayor y menor. Te recomiendo esto:

- **list[0]:** coge el primer elemento de la lista
- **list[-1]:** coge el último elemento de la lista

```
list = []

for i in range(0, 4):
  list.append(int(input('Ingrese un número\n')))

# Ordenar lista
list.sort()

# Numero menor
print(list[0])
# Numero mayor
print(list[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

El consejo es que a partir de 3 o incluso de dos dos variables te busques otro método más simple y legible. Ahora bien, si quieres implementarlo con condicionales como un reto, dos consejos:

- Tienes que asegurarte de que **todas las posibilidades estén cubiertas**. En tu implementación ésto no ocurre. Ten en cuenta que hay 24 permutaciones posibles para el caso de cuatro variables.
- En vez de usar un `else` con un solo `if` dentro, usa `elif`.

No obstante, es mucho más simple si usas dos variables más, una para el máximo y otra para el mínimo:

```
a = int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))
b = int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))
c = int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))
d = int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))

mayor = menor = a

if b > mayor:
    mayor = b
elif b < menor:
    menor = b

if c > mayor:
    mayor = c
elif c < menor:
    menor = c

if d > mayor:
    mayor = d
elif d < menor:
    menor = d

if menor == mayor:
    print(f"Los números son iguales {a} = {b} = {c} = {d}")
else:
    print(f"El número mayor es {mayor}")
    print(f"El número menor es {menor}")
```

O más escalable aún, usa un ciclo:

```
NUMS = 4

mayor = float("-inf")
menor = float("inf")
for _ in range(NUMS):
    if (n:= int(input('Ingrese un número\n'))) > mayor:
        mayor  = n
    elif n < menor:
        menor = n

if menor == mayor:
    print(f"Los números son iguales")
else:
    print(f"El número mayor es {mayor}")
    print(f"El número menor es {menor}")
```

La otra posibilidad es usar un contenedor y `sorted()`/`list.sort()` cómo muestra @Gonzalo-GC en su respuesta o también `max()`/`min()`:

```
NUMS = 4

numeros = [int(input('Ingrese un número\n')) for _ in range(NUMS)]

if (mayor:= max(numeros)) == (menor:= min(numeros)):
    print(f"Los números son iguales, todos son {mayor}")
else:
    print(f"El número mayor es {mayor}")
    print(f"El número menor es {menor}")
```